# disable javascript from running on links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that reloads an iframe whenever the browser screen is clicked (works perfectly). I was wondering how I would go about disabling the javascript from running on certain links?

Here is my current script:

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    if (event===tichack) event= window.event;
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement;

   document.getElementById("tichack").src = "http://link.com?"+(+new Date());
};
```

Example would be something like this i suppose? (obviously incorrect) but will give you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve, did allot of searching but have had no luck?:

```
onclick="javascript:disabled=true;"
```

Comment: `onclick="javascript:return false;..."`

Comment: You want to disabled click on 'tichack' element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to identify what the target of your click is and, if the target is equal to one of the links you don't want triggering this, return from the function without refreshing the iframe.

```
var links = /* a collection of elements you don't want triggering the iframe refresh */,
    count = links.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    if (target === links[i]) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems like my best option, could I have an example of how to implement this in my current javascript and what would be the correct syntax for the integrating the links?

Comment: I would need to know what the links are you want to have this work for.

Comment: there would be many, would defining it by id or class be a better solution? for example: 
`if (target.id!== 'menu','panel','footer') {return;}` thank for your help and your time.

Comment: Define a variable that is a collection of elements you don't want triggering the iframe refresh.  (Without a concrete example, it's hard to be more specific.)  Then loop through this collection comparing to `target`, and if there is a match return out of the function. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.target.id != 'tichack') return;
    document.getElementById("tichack").src = "http://link.com?" + (+new Date());
};
```

Here, the document click event will work for the `tichack` link only.

[**SIMPLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpkHT/)

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways:

- in the document.onclick, check the target element if it's a certain link, and then don't do anything. I.e. `if (target.id == '...') { return; }`
- make sure that the click never arrives at the document.onclick. Because of how the DOM Event model works, if you cancel an onclick event at a low level (i.e. at a link itself) it will not bubble up and arrive at the document.onclick. So the following code works:

  `<a href='...' onclick='return false;'>click here!</a>`

See http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/10/a-crash-course-in-how-dom-events-work.html for more information on the DOM Event model!